# Import a pyi (type stub file) into a normal python module

Tags: python, import, python-import, stub, pyi

I have a program (like a macro) that runs within a parent program and imports an API module from that program (lets call it `foo`). The problem is that that module only exists within that program, so I can't do things like run [pydocmd](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/pydoc-markdown) outside the software because the script throws a ReferenceError. To aid in my own development I have create a type stub file, `foo.pyi`, in my project directory. What I would like to do is import that type stub as a normal Python file if the import fails, to provide dummy functions and properties. Something like:

```py
try:
  import foo
except ImportError:
  from . import foo.pyi
```

This raises an error, however, as it's trying to import `pyi` from the `foo` library that does not exist in the project folder. The only other option I can think of is to have an identical copy of the .pyi file as, say "dummy_foo.py" but then I have to maintain two copies of the same file in one repo. I'd rather not do that.

Comment: I'd also like to know how to do this

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on the stub file? Those are usually used for type-hinting, but your question makes it sound like you have actual logic in it? I have a fairly good idea on how to solve your question as long as I understood it correctly. I just want to make sure I've got it right before answering. It would help a TON if you could add an MRE to your question (also for future visitors).

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/43602557/371334

Answer (score 2):

I found this question, but my problem was about type checking. In my case `pyi` file contains class definition (so type hints are working), but the library doesn't. Solution is in checking `typing.TYPE_CHECKING`:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from library import _PrivateClass

def foo(x: "_PrivateClass"):
    ...
```

Comment: `from __future__ import annotations` gives a nice way, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74537308/21115).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this a while back; should still work I think:

```
import importlib


def import_stub(stubs_path, module_name):
    sys.path_hooks.insert(0,
        importlib.machinery.FileFinder.path_hook(
            (importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader, ['.pyi']))
    )
    sys.path.insert(0, stubs_path)
    
    try:
        return importlib.import_module(module_name)
    finally:
        sys.path.pop(0)
        sys.path_hooks.pop(0)
```